# Migration of app from target sdk 28 to 30 giving library error

Tags: android, build, androidx

I am migrating my application from target sdk 28 to 30 because to upload it on playstore its required but its giving library error for all the libraries.

Below is app level build file with all the required libraries.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devakya.kinderstudyzone"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "38d403ad-a92d-487f-afa2-c9b1a8c2907d",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // <------

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'server_url', server_url
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03'

    // androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:30.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:30.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:30.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.4.3"
   // implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"
    //implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
   // implementation 'com.android.support:design:30.0.0'//appcompact
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.8@aar'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation project(':bettervideoplayer')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.mjn1369:prettydialog:1.0.4'
    implementation project(path: ':SmoothCheckBox-master')
    implementation 'com.github.bosphere.android-fadingedgelayout:fadingedgelayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How I resolve this error for libraries .which library version I change for it.

I am getting version crashes issue for aome libraires but I am unable to resolve it.

Comment: Please share the logcat from when the crash is happening.

Comment: Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

Comment: com.android.support:support-v4 is a little bit outdated. The recommended way is to [migrate to AnddroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). AndroidStudio provides sophisticated migration tasks for performing the migration nearly automatically.